# Expecting : or ; for array find_all

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am not sure where my syntax is wrong here and I'm new to Ruby.

```
class someClass
  def self.some_method(amount, some_array=[1,2,3,4])        
    if some_array.include?(amount)
      return [amount]
    end
    else
      some_array.sort
      some_array.find_all{[d] d < amount}
    end
  end

  some_array.sort
  someArray.find_all{[d] d < amount}
end
end
```

I'm getting the error "expected ; or end of line"

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
      @validValues = some_array.find_all{[d] d < amount}
```

I know it's probably something stupid that I just don't know about the language yet but I just do not see it.

Comment: I removed the @validValues var, not needed

Comment: if this is off topic then where should it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someArray.find_all{|d| d < amount}`, redundant `end` after `if` statment:

```
class SameClass
  def self.some_method(amount, some_array = [1,2,3,4])
    if some_array.include?(amount)
      amount
    else
      some_array.sort
      some_array.find_all { |d| d < amount }
    end
  end
end
```

Then, you can use this method:

```
SameClass.some_method(1)
#=> 1
SameClass.some_method(5, [2,3,4])
#=> [2, 3, 4]
SameClass.some_method(5, [6,7,8])
#=> []
```

Comment: That's valid Ruby code right there. If you're having trouble executing it I think you've got something else in your code that's confusing Ruby.

Comment: answer edited. Please, look instances in the answer.

Comment: just copy my code. You still have syntax errors.

Comment: omg I am an idiot.  I had [] instead of || My head is certainly up my ass today